# Tensorflow 2.x: Convert byte string to int in map

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TFRecordDataset of images.  Each record has an image, an integer label, and a byte-array ID.  The byte-array is a hex representation of some number.

I wish to seed the random operations with a derivative of the ID.  How do I do that?

The following attempt failed:

```py
def func(image, label, idnum):
    '''Example idnum: b"abcdef012"'''
    seed = tf.py_function(func=lambda x: int(x.numpy().decode(), 16),
                          inp=[idnum], Tout=tf.int64)
    ran = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), seed=seed)
```

Here's the error message:

```
TypeError: Expected int for argument 'seed2' not <tf.Tensor 'random_uniform/mod:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int64>.
```

In ordinary python, I would convert such a byte-string to an int as follows:

```py
x = b'abcdef012'
i = int(x.decode(), 16)
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, TF doesnt seem to parse strings in the same was as normal python.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding a binary string (tensor) into an int (tensor) is actually quite straight-forward:

```py
tf.io.decode_raw(tf.constant(b'ABC'), tf.uint8)
```

-> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_raw

The bigger issue here is that TensorFlow considers seeds to be configuration, not data. Hence, `tf.random.uniform` and other random operations expect the seed to be a 'Python integer', not a tensor (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform). That means, they don't expect to receive the seed as input tensor during **graph execution**, but as constant during **graph creation** (or rather, tracing https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#tracing). Note that Dataset transformations like `Dataset.map` are translated into graph operations, capturing all parameters that aren't tensors.

This should also explain the error message that you are seeing.

The solution to this depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you keep your global random seed fixed (`tf.random.set_seed`), then the values of `ran` are actually fully deterministic and you could just precompute and store them inside the TFRecords. If not, an option would be to compute `ran` values for each image upfront in Python, then use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to turn the list into a Dataset and then zip the Dataset with the TFRecordDataset.